# Date from Character and Numeric Columns in R

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I have a data set with the format. How do I combine these to a date format column?

```
year   mon  day  

1997    Jul   3   
1997    Jul   1   
1997    Sep   10   
1997    Sep   1     
1998    Oct   10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `paste` the 3 columns together and convert it to date using `as.Date` :

```
df <- transform(df, date = as.Date(paste(year, mon, day), '%Y %b %d'))
```

Can also use `ymd` from `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(date = ymd(paste(year, mon, day)))

#  year mon day       date
#1 1997 Jul   3 1997-07-03
#2 1997 Jul   1 1997-07-01
#3 1997 Sep  10 1997-09-10
#4 1997 Sep   1 1997-09-01
#5 1998 Oct  10 1998-10-10
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1998L), mon = c("Jul", 
"Jul", "Sep", "Sep", "Oct"), day = c(3L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar answer with @Ronak Shah, using `anytime` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(year_mon_date = anydate(str_c(V1, V2, V3)))
           
#     V1  V2 V3 year_mon_date
# 1 1997 Jul  3    1997-07-03
# 2 1997 Jul  1    1997-07-01
# 3 1997 Sep 10    1997-09-10
# 4 1997 Sep  1    1997-09-01
# 5 1998 Oct 10    1998-10-10
```

Data

```
structure(list(V1 = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1998L), V2 = c("Jul", 
"Jul", "Sep", "Sep", "Oct"), V3 = c(3L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: You have used `str_c()` but you don't load `stringr`.

Comment: I have added. Thanks @Darren Tai, dear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `make_date()` from `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = make_date(year, match(mon, month.abb), day))

#   year mon day       date
# 1 1997 Jul   3 1997-07-03
# 2 1997 Jul   1 1997-07-01
# 3 1997 Sep  10 1997-09-10
# 4 1997 Sep   1 1997-09-01
# 5 1998 Oct  10 1998-10-10
```

where `month.abb` is a built-in vector storing the abbreviations for the English month names.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1998L), mon = c("Jul", 
"Jul", "Sep", "Sep", "Oct"), day = c(3L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```